# outliner : to cycle the find result in outliner

Tags: outliner

I have objects which is part of multiple collections. If i select the object in 3d view and want to find it in outliner, i will type '.' . The outliner will scroll and the selected obj will be highlighted. But it only show the one stored in top most collection. If i link this object to many collections. I want it like cycle the result (something like 'find next' function ) to reveal from other collection as well. Maybe like typing the '.' for the second or third time will show the next found object.

So far i have to copy the name of the object and paste it on the search bar.

I prefer the fancy and faster way by cycle the result.

Comment: I don't think that is possible, but a quicker way to filter is to click and drag the object from the outliner and drop it in the search bar

Comment: Cool , i didn't know that trick.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly a 'Find Next' .. but there's a dropdown next to the *Filter* checkboxes which can restrict the outliner display, to, among others, only selected objects.

I've assigned that dropdown to the <kbd>Numpad /</kbd> key, analagous to isolating in the 3D view. 'Selected' restricts the outliner view to (all) references to objects selected in the viewport.